# Adding wall sconce fixture - stud in way

Tags: wiring, lighting

My wife wants three light fixtures mounted over the vanity in the bathroom. One of them is positioned directly over a wall stud. To install an electric box, can I saw/chisel through the stud (not load bearing), or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [saddle mounted box](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HEKU8G) -- these are most commonly used for fans, but can be used for a light as well.  (Link and picture are merely representative.)

[image: saddle mount box]

Comment: You just beat me - this is the exact pic I was about to post :P

Comment: Suggest you make that the end of the chain of conductors, as you might run foul of box fill restrictions if you try to chain through that one. (Or double-check the math on box fill and whatever junction box you get...)